# How do I get my image in python to appear?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have code that moves my beach ball image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlp19.png) with wrapping around the edges. When I run the code, I do not get any errors but a blank black screen appears without the ball. When I exit out of the program, the image of the ball appears for a second before closing the program.

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([640,640])
screen.fill([0, 0, 0])
my_ball = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
x=0
y=0
x_speed=5
running=True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,0], [x, y, 0, 0], 0)
    x=x+x_speed
if x>screen.get_width():
    x=0
screen.blit(my_ball,[x, y])
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The screen is staying black because the drawing operations are never flushed to the display. Your code has a simple indentation bug, everything from `if x>screen...` to `pygame.display.flip()` (inclusive) should be part of the `while running` loop.

Comment: Thank you that was the issue. I feel silly that I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 2):

You should put

```
screen.blit(my_ball,[x, y])
pygame.display.flip()
```

inside the while loop like this:

```
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,0], [x, y, 0, 0], 0)
    x=x+x_speed
    screen.blit(my_ball,[x, y])
    if x>screen.get_width():
        x=0

    pygame.display.flip()
```

and probably the if statement as well

also instead of

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,0], [x, y, 0, 0], 0)
```

you can simply use

```
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

which just fills the screen with specified color

Answer (score 0):

The screen is staying black because the drawing operations are never flushed to the display.

Your code has a simple indentation bug, everything from if `x>screen...` to `pygame.display.flip()` (inclusive) should be part of the while running loop.

e.g.:

```
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
    #pygame.time.delay(20)    # don't delay the main loop, use clock.tick()

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,0], [x, y, 0, 0], 0)

    x=x+x_speed
    if x>screen.get_width():
        x=0
    screen.blit(my_ball,[x, y])
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```